# Is there a way to remove BOM from UTF-8 streams with Guava?

Tags: java, utf-8, guava, byte-order-mark

Is there a way to remove BOM from UTF-8 streams with Guava?

The Apache Commons IO Library has [BOMInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html). I already use Google Guava and don't want to use Apache Commons just for one this feature.

Comment: Isn't this easy to implement yourself? If the stream starts with the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) then just skip those bytes.

Comment: Yes it is, but why do I need to invent the bicycle? =)

Comment: Do you need a library for something that's just a few lines of code to implement?

Comment: @Jesper: It's not exactly easy to implement if you want to use it as an `InputStream`. You need to read in a few bytes and either discard them or keep them in the stream. No big deal and surely nothing what could make me include a library, but something what I'd reuse if available.

Comment: @Jesper look at the wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding There's a lot of different BOMs. I think it's better to reuse some library that would take care of each case than implement my own for one particular case (and to fix all possible bugs). BTW, such a functionality does not have any business value. And it's a good question why it's not handled by Java itself.

Comment: @MaxRomanovsky You specifically mentioned UTF-8, in which the BOM is just three bytes `EF BB BF`.